# How to intrepret this java interface definition

Tags: java, interface

I'm dealing with a new codebase. what exactly does this interface definition mean? This is how I understand it: InfoPage extends WholePage. The generic is identified as SELF which has to be a type that has extended InfoPage. Did I get it right? or there is more to it?

```
public interface InfoPage<SELF extends InfoPage<SELF>> extends WholePage<SELF> {
Upload<SELF> bringupUploadDialog();
SELF upload();
}
```

Comment: Almost. `SELF` has to extend `InfoPage<SELF>`. E.g., `class InfoPageImpl implements InfoPage<InfoPageImpl>`. The implication is that `SELF` should be a reference to the same class, but that's not enforceable at compile time.

Comment: Search for Java self referencing generics.